# Save image from URL extracted from an XML file

Tags: php, xml

I extract an image url from an xml file.
I put the url into a variable and then I try to save the image of the url into a folder in my PC.
But i get this error: Warning: copy(the url) [function.copy]: failed to open stream:

This is the code that doesn't work.

```
$urlimage='http://www.etc....';
copy($urlimage, '../../myfolder/'."imagename".'.jpg');
```

Instead if I write this code

```
copy('http://www.etc....', '../../myfolder/'."imagename".'.jpg');
```

it works.

I made a var_dump to $urlimage, this is the result:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { [0]=> string(192) " http://www.etc...." }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$urlimage` variable is actually an object, so you have to cast the element to a string first, i.e.:

```
copy((string)$urlimage, '../../myfolder/imagename.jpg');
```

Also, you should probably trim its contents; because `trim()` expects a string, you don't need the cast:

```
copy(trim($urlimage), '../../myfolder/imagename.jpg');
```

Comment: I forgot to write that I also tried to cast $urlimage.
Now I've done it again and when I var_dump $urlimage I get:
string(192) " http://theurl.jpg"

But I still get the same error

Comment: @Aimcorz You missed the update to my answer; you have to apply `trim()` because the string starts with a space character.

Comment: It works now. I didn't think about trim(). Thank you